# What password should I enter for SSH?

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to learn how to use SSH and it's kinda hard for me. I installed PuTTY (windows 7 32-bit). It asked for my IP so I searched 'What is my ip' and pasted it in. Then in the 'command prompt style box' I entered my username 'dell'. Now it's asking for password. I'm really confused  because my laptop has no password and there's no password I know of. Can you guys help?

Entering nothing doesn't work:
[image]

Comment: If your laptop don't have any password then just press enter when asking for password

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work :(

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Putty is just a command line interface, that will allow you to run commands like `ssh`.

However, if you want to SSH into your machine you have to install an SSH server on your machine.

There are multiple solution on the web:

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/

Answer (score 1):

`122.162.179.255` is likely the IP address of your network router / ADSL modem / etc and not your Windows PC (which won't have an SSH server installed by default).

There really is very little to learn about SSH itself, at least for basic day to day use.

If you want to learn how to use a UNIX-style command prompt then consider installing [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) or setting up a Linux installation on a separate computer (maybe a Raspberry Pi).